# Is there a way to send a user email when user object is created?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

In the system I am building user CAN NOT register them selves. The users are added by one of the system admins. So there is no user registration form or view. The registration is only being done in the admin so I guess that the send_mail has to be over there also (or am I wrong)?

I need to send an automatic email to the user when he/she is being created and only then (not on every save of the model).

Can any one help with this? Is there a built-in something for that? or how do I do that?

I've read about the create_user user Manager, but I thought there is a better way then editing a manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register a callback on the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for the User model. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
# note: untested code

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def email_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:  # only for new users
        new_user = kwargs.["instance"]
        # send email to new_user.email ..

post_save.connect(email_new_user, sender=User)
```

Note the `if kwargs["created"]:` condition which checks if this is a newly created User instance.

Comment: Just one more question, where do i put the post_save.connect function? I am guess that this is what connect the function to the signal, but where to add it to so the save method will know to call it? and do i need to add anything in the settings.py also for this to work? Thank you again, Erez

Comment: The most common place to register signal callbacks is in `models.py`. You don't need any additional settings for signals to work.

Comment: OK, I guess that i am not explaining my self very good. The models.py of what app? should i create an app just for sending registration mails for users? or edit the auth.User models.py or in the UserProfile app models.py file? And this is for the connect for the signal, what about the function? I am guessing that i will put it in the views of the same app that i put the connect in, but not sure... I am reading the Signals docs and can't find anything about this.... Thank you and sorry for all the newbie questions.... But This is the first time i am trying something like that.... :-)

Comment: To clarify, you add it to `models.py` in any one of your apps (not `contrib.auth`). The `post_save.connect()` method register your method as a callback which gets run every time any object is saved. The `sender=User` argument limits that callback to the `User` model. As long as your `models.py` file is loaded by django, the callback will be registered.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), which has a `created` argument sent with the signal. If created is true, send your email.

**Edit**

Shawn Chin beat me to it. Accept his answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [signals framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). A post-save signal on User objects will be appropriate, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders) for a similar example.

Comment: Thank you Shany, but still, In the signals there is no signal for user created, there is for save. and i don't want to send the mail every time the user profile is being saved, just on creation, and I'm not that expert in python/django yet. I know i am asking a lot, but can you be more specific on how to do that? thank you, Erez