# How can I send an email to user on new user addition to django admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to send an email with login details to user emailaddress whenever Admin adds new user to admin site.

I know Django provides send_mail module for that,but I don't know where should I put this code
and override some view to send automatic mails on new user addition.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

How can i do it?

**I tried putting this code in my models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def email_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs["created"]:  # only for new users
            new_user = kwargs["instance"] 
            print new_user.email
            #send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)


post_save.connect(email_new_user, sender=User)
```

But its not printing anything on command line. I think the function is not getting called whenever i create a new user.Don't know why?

Comment: This was just asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583212/115845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [hook the `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for the `User` model.

Comment: Can You help me telling what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems I can see in the code as I can see it, above.

- First, the `def email_new_user()` is wrongly indented. If that is not a formatting error here, correct it.
- `new_user = kwargs.["instance"]`  is wrong syntax. It really should be `kwargs["instance"]`

And then, do you have an SMTP server running? Can you send email from the shell? If not, configure that and then try it again. It should work.

Comment: Thanks Lakshman,indentation was wrong. Now the function is getting called, but is thr any way to include the user email field in first step of user creation rather than in second step,because django creates the object in first step and by that time i dont have the user email-id to send a mail.

Comment: Thats a different question actually. You should include both UserForm and the ProfileForm in the same page and save them, only if both forms validate.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem was, Django user cretion consists of two steps. First django asks for **username**, **password** and **password confirmation**, and when you press save (or save and continue edit) your save method fired without **e-mail** information. Since django will accept that request as a **newly created** record, your signal will fire for a record with no e-mail information...

If django handles admin save diffrently and do not mark a newly created record instance as ***created*** you shall not have any problem, but probably django will not do that.

UPDATE: Some possible reasons are:

- You need django 1.3, so check your django version with **python manage.py version** and update it if required...
- Best place for your your models.py files

> You can put signal handling and registration code anywhere you like. However, you'll need to make sure that the module it's in gets imported early on so that the signal handling gets registered before any signals need to be sent. This makes your app's models.py a good place to put registration of signal handlers.

These are basic problems...

Comment: I tried even print "testing" instead of print new_user.email but it's also not printing.what could be the problem?

Comment: Django version I am running is 1.3 and the signal code is in models.py file.....Thanks for replying, but its still not working

Comment: Did you check with putting an assertion (or something else) to the very first line of your receiver function to check if you have problems about if controls?

Comment: Yes it seems to be not calling when a new user adds to database, I m still stuck with this problem :(

Comment: I had a similar problem with __user_logged_in__ signal. Updating django to the latest repository version solved the problem. So if you install django from cvs repository, update your django.