# How can I show a "Hello"+username Screen to All other users who are not superuser in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I want only superuser to see all models and edit/add them.But if a normal user like staff status user logs in i want him to show a screen saying "Hello"+username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really restrict access to the admin.

You can create a decorator to do add the functionality of `@superuser_required` to the admin site, or simply just all people that are `is_staff` as otherwise.

Comment: could you Plz help me in this Question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593348/how-can-i-send-an-email-to-user-on-new-user-addition-to-django-admin-site